# How to read a txt file and load the contents into an arraylist?

Tags: c#, file-io

I am new to C# and to programming in general. I am trying to read the contents of a txt file and load them to an `arraylist`. I can't figure out what condition to use in my `while` loop.

```
void LoadArrayList()
{
    TextReader tr;
    tr = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Maattt\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\actor\\actors.txt");

    string Actor;
    while (ActorArrayList != null)
    {
        Actor = tr.ReadLine();
        if (Actor == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        ActorArrayList.Add(Actor);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Search for `File.ReadAllLines`, that should get you close to what you need.

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` on the first place. Use generic `List<T>` instead.

Comment: `variable` name should start with a small letter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 void LoadArrayList()
{
    TextReader tr;
    tr = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Maattt\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\actor\\actors.txt");

    string Actor;
    Actor = tr.ReadLine();
    while (Actor != null)
    {
        ActorArrayList.Add(Actor);
        Actor = tr.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: The same thing happened with this as did with the above code. It went through the loop 5 times.

Comment: Is that a good or a bad thing?  Without knowing what's in your file I have no way of telling.  Step through the code in the debugger and look at the value of Actor for each iteration of the loop.  This will give you some insight into what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just **2 lines** of code

```
string[] Actor = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Maattt\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\actor\\actors.txt");
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Actor);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be

```
 void LoadArrayList()
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Maattt\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\actor\actors.txt");

   // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
   foreach (string Actor in lines)
   {
       ActorArrayList.Add(Actor);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange it like this:

```
    Actor = tr.ReadLine();
    while (Actor != null)
    {
        ActorArrayList.Add(Actor);
        Actor = tr.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation for the `TextReader.ReadLine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx), you'll see that it returns either a `string`, or `null` if there are no more lines. So, what you can do is loop and check null against the results of the `ReadLine` method.

```
while(tr.ReadLine() != null)
{
    // We know there are more items to read
}
```

With the above, though, you're not capturing the result of `ReadLine`. So you need to declare a string to capture the result and to use inside the while loop:

```
string line;
while((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ActorArrayList.Add(line);
}
```

Also, I would suggest using a generic list, such as `List<T>` instead of the non-generic `ArrayList`. Using something like `List<T>` gives you more type safety and reduces the possibility of invalid assignments or casts.